# AutoHotKey - Run a program once send several times

Tags: autohotkey

I am pretty new to AutoHotkey, but I managed it to start my desired program and send an Enter-Key to it, but the probleme here is, the program should only start once and if started it should only receive that enter key, when I press the key stroke again and again it should only send that enter key.

And the program should should stay in the background and not focus after it receives the enter key.

My Code:

```
#n::
Run F:\V..c.exe
Send {enter}
return
```

Comment: you mean you want to run the program `V..c.exe` only once ?

Comment: yes, and if the program is up, it should only receive the enterkey int the background

Answer (score 1):

Detect if the [process exists](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Process.htm) and start the program [minimized](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Run.htm), then [wait for its window](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/WinWait.htm) to appear.

```
#n::
  process, exist, PROGRAM.EXE
  if (errorlevel = 0) {
    run, d:\program.exe, , min
    winwait, ahk_class PROGRAM_WINDOW_CLASS
  }
  controlSend, , {Enter}, ahk_class PROGRAM_WINDOW_CLASS
  ;or use the line below
  ;controlSend, ahk_parent, {Enter}, ahk_class PROGRAM_WINDOW_CLASS
  return
```

Replace `PROGRAM.EXE` with the executable name of your program and `PROGRAM_WINDOW_CLASS` with the window class as seen in the Autohotkey Window Spy utility available in Start menu or in the folder of the Autohotkey (AU3_Spy.exe) or in the right click menu of the Autohotkey tray icon.

---

Instead of running the program minimized it's also possible to use `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE` flag of `shellExecute`, so you can replace the `run, d:\program,, min` with this:

```
dllCall("shell32\ShellExecute", uint,0, uint,0, str,"d:\program.exe", uint,0, uint,0
        ,uint,SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE:=4)
```

Comment: Try replacing `winwait, ahk_class PROGRAM_WINDOW_CLASS` with `sleep 100` which will sleep for 100 milliseconds.

Comment: It's an wpf(c#) program which I wrote, so should I provide something from my program ? ok, I tried to use `sleep`, but he still does not excecute the method in my program. (even changing `sleep` to `1000`

Comment: Run the abovementioned Window Spy and hover the mouse over the required element (button or whatever) in your program's window and copy its name in `controlSend, elementName, {Enter}, ............`

Comment: Ok, will try by the way the log looks like this http://postimg.org/image/i7616ts3n/ ,after calling it twice

Comment: You haven't replaced PROGRAM_WINDOW_CLASS with the actual value?

Comment: ok, now  the log looks like :`001: Return (16.19)
002: Process,exist,program.exe
003: if (errorlevel = 0)  
007: ControlSend,,{Enter},ahk_class HwndWrapper[program.exe;;85633391-e8f1-45fb-a002-1a0b99872d74] (0.08)
010: Return (7.97)` and I replaced all `ahk_class PROGRAM_WINDOW_CLASS` with that name, still not working just calls the program without action.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
hasran := false
#n::
if (!hasran) {
    Run F:\V..c.exe
    hasran := true
}
Send {enter}
return
```

It wont check if that windows exists, but it will only run the program once. then you can navigate to that program and it will only hit the enter key. (if that program is not gui I dont think you can send key events to it)

Comment: works only if the window is active, but then I could just press the enter key, like I did before ...

Comment: ok, now I had the time to check this. your code works either way, but the intendation  is very much misleading. `hasran := true` will be executed, **no matter** if it was set to `false` before. I simply hope you guys know that. If so, again - sorry.

Comment: @Blauhirn ...  you are right! (replaced `!hasran` with `hasran` and caused unexpected stuff) but I see many people use this syntax so I switched to this. I was a brace fan but I changed. Now Im going back to using braces. thanks for telling that.